# Getting error while creating VM in Azure using powershell command

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to create Windows 7 VM on Azure using powershell command

```
$dclocation = 'East Asia'
$cloudSvcName = 'MyNewCloudServiceName' 
$image = '03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Windows-7-Enterprise-x64-en.us-201407.01'
$adminPassword = 'Admin@123' 
$vmname = 'MyVMName' 
New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Name $vmname -ImageName $image -Location $dclocation -InstanceSize 'Basic_A0'
```

On Running the above code i am getting error :

```
New-AzureQuickVM : BadRequest: A ProvisioningConfigurationSet was not found in the ConfigurationSet collection of the virtual machine with name MyVMName. When creating a virtual machine from an image, ProvisioningConfigurationSet must be specified.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-AzureQuickVM -Windows -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Name $vmname -ImageName $i ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureQuickVM], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.PersistentVMs.NewQuickVM
```

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass in values for `-AdminUsername` and `-Password`, e.g.

```
New-AzureQuickVM -Windows `
    -ServiceName $cloudSvcName `
    -Name $vmname `
    -ImageName $image `
    -Location $dclocation `
    -InstanceSize 'Basic_A0' `
    -AdminUsername $adminUsername `
    -Password $adminPassword
```